# Connect configuration item (CI) from CMDB to Customer

Tags: otrs, ticket-system

I have the latest version of OTRS(5.0.14) with the following packages:

- DynamicFieldITSMConfigItem
- GeneralCatalog
- ITSM-CIAttributeCollection
- ITSMConfigurationManagement
- ITSMCore

Is it possible to relate CIs to company and/or to customer user natively or with some free package?

Is it possible to have an auto-complete field which will populates only with CIs of the selected company/customer? See:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to programming

Answer (score 0):

Owner field in CI definition can be used to define the customer.

Comment: Yes, I've already implemented it. Is it possible to have an auto-complete field which will populates only with CIs of the selected company/customer? See: http://i.imgur.com/hYTUl92.jpg

Comment: This needs customizations

Comment: Is there some free package available or can you point me to some examples of customizations for otrs? Will it be a hard customization without knowing perl?

Comment: No free package available

Comment: If it's hard depends on your current knowledge. From experience I can tell you that it's more annoying than difficult to write customizations for the OTRS. There is relatively little documentation on how to do it and you definitely need to be able to read perl, because to figure out how stuff works you need to look in the code. Writing customizations especially for the frontend is a mess, because it's rather difficult to debug and work with (IMHO).